# How can I convert a column "1. April 2000" into a datetime column?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I tried to convert the column "Datum Response Restaurant" into the type "datetime" with the following code. However the error "Unknown string format: 1. April 2000" occurs. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

```
reviews_english2['Datum Response Restaurant'] =pd.to_datetime(reviews_english2['Datum Response Restaurant'])
```

Comment: Pandas does not know how to parse the string `'1. April 2000'`

Comment: What's the locale, German?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the format of the datetime column. Something like:

```py
reviews_english2['Datum Response Restaurant'] =pd.to_datetime(reviews_english2['Datum Response Restaurant'], format="%d. %A %Y")
```